# Как установить ширину элемента который находится в container(bootstrap), так чтобы она начиналась с начала страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Что изображено на макете PSD:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что получается в верстке :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.bg{
  background:red;
  height:60px;
}
.container{
  max-width:360px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5 bg">
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo"><img></div>
   <div class="title"></div>
   <div class="tel"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
   width: 100%
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
}

 .logo {
   width: 30%;
 }

    .logo img {
       width:100%;
    }
```

Как-то так)

Comment: justify-content: space-between сделай

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо container написать класс container-fluid.